# Why there is not a CV_64S type in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

When I tried to create a Mat to store my data, I found there is no CV_64S type defined. I have no way to store my data of type `long`. What should I do?

Comment: there is not an int64 depth type for cv::Mat, one can use `CV_USRTYPE1` for such cases, however it probably won't work with almost any function from OpenCV. Do you really need it to be in long?

Comment: CV_USRTYPE1 has only 4 bytes. It can not be used to contain a long data.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the data (as in, why do you need to get it into the `Mat`)?

Comment: Because I want to save long data into a image.

Answer (score -1):

There is int64 type in OpenCV. Look at this [*.h file](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/82c477c9f7d5a2cc6f70b51d61584a2dca605c8c/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/hal/intrin.hpp)

Comment: Yes, there is. But int64 is unavailable in Mat's data type. For example,  `DataType<double>::type` indicates CV_64F, while `DataType<int64>::type` is undefined.